# Microsoft Graph API search functionality only returns newly added files after a few minutes delay

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

The search functionality in Graph API doesn't return newly added files until several minutes after they have been added. Is there a fix for this on horizon, or an alternative function we could use that won't have the delay?

Answer (score 3):

That is a known issue with the service...

> Even then, due to the distributed nature of the service, it might take 15 minutes before files, messages and events entities are available for use for this user, through the Microsoft Graph API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues